# How to create array of StringBuilder initialized with ""?

Tags: java

How to create an array by calling args contructor?

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[100];
```

But if I check sb[0] it is null. I want that sb[0] to sb[99] initialized with "".

Following results in an error:

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[100]("");
```

**EDIT:**
Or I have to do this:

```
for(StringBuilder it:sb)
{
  it=new StringBuilder("");
}
```

Comment: You'll have to write a loop.

Comment: or just for fun : `StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[]{"", "".... 100}`;

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer The edit you have made won't work as you would be reassigning the value for `it` which would not be reflected in the array. There are 3 nearly identical answers you have which explain what to do

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All your code will do is initialise an array ready for 100 StringBuilders. It won't actually populate it.

You could do this:

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[100];

for (int i = 0; i < sb.length; i++) {
    sb[i] = new StringBuilder("");
}
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: or `sb[i] = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: @all: A lot for people here are deleting their comments. Once they realize that they are wrong :D

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately I missed most of that debate which I accidentally sparked. :)
As for using foreach, I'm guessing here that because the values aren't initialised, you can't foreach through them. Was that the outcome of the debate?

Comment: @CraigBrett:  As far as I think java will create a local variable ex: 

    `for(StringBuilder sb: sbArray)` here `sb` is local variable, so if I do `sb=new StringBuilder()` then it is of no use, as after the loop `sb` is destroyed.

Comment: Ah, so the changes you make to sb aren't propagated back to the array where it came from in the foreach. Good to know. You even learn something new on StackOverflow by answering it seems.

Answer (score 3):

It will always be `null`. You have to initialize it manually if you want `""` in there.

Instead you could access the array by a method which returns `""` if the value is `null`.

Comment: @Edd.. Err.. Java is not Pass by Reference. It always passes by value. In case of a reference also, it passes it by value of reference.

Comment: @Rohit that's why i said 'effectively'

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder[] sb = new StringBuilder[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    sb[i] = new StringBuilder("");
}
```

Comment: @Andreas_D. Is the answer modified after your comment, or this was the original answer? If original, then why it wouldn't compile?

Comment: @RohitJain I modified the answer. I forgot to create the object.

Comment: Rohit, the comment was *before* the correction. *Now* it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

All values in any array are `null` unless they are set... you need to initialise each value manually

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[100];
for(int i=0; i<sb.length; i++) {
    sb[i]=new StringBuilder();
}
```

or...

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[]{new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder(), etc}
```

(I'd recommend the first method for an array with lots of entries)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting application of pass-by-reference in Java.

Please note that the following will work -

```
StringBuilder[] array = new StringBuilder[10];
for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array [i] = new StringBuilder("");
}
```

But the following will NOT work -

```
StringBuilder[] array = new StringBuilder[10];
for (StringBuilder sb: array) {
    sb = new StringBuilder("");
}
```

This is because in the second case, the variable `sb` is assigned reference to a new StringBuilder instead of referring to the arrays' elements. The array elements do not change, as `sb` loses reference to them.

Answer (score 0):

All values in any array are null unless they are set... you need to initialise each value manually

```
StringBuilder[] sb=new StringBuilder[100];
for(int i=0; i<sb.length; i++) {
    sb[i]=new StringBuilder();
}
```